# loginctl enable-linger/disable-linger ... but reading linger-status?

Tags: systemd

I know how to enable/disable lingering with `loginctl`.

But up to now I found no way to query the status of a user.

I want to know: Is lingering enable for user `foo`?

How can I access this information?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can show a list of lingering users with

```
ls /var/lib/systemd/linger
```

because

```
loginctl enable-linger $USER
loginctl disable-linger $USER
```

do the equivalent of

```
touch /var/lib/systemd/linger/$USER
rm /var/lib/systemd/linger/$USER
```

Comment: Note: folder `/var/lib/systemd/linger` does not exist until you « linger » your first user

Comment: @Jocelyndelalande On Debian unstable I got that linger directory, even though it is empty, I never had a lingering user (95% sure), nor is it part of a package.

Answer (score 26):

`loginctl user-status foo` shows linger status.

Comment: I am unsure if this really works. Some minutes ago this printed a tree for a test-user which has not lingering enabled. Now, some minutes later, the output is "Failed to get user: No user '1003' known or logged in". I will use the solution from Markus Kuhn (check if file /var/lib/systemd/linger/$USER exists)

Answer (score 20):

The best I found for check it in scripts (programmatically):

```
loginctl show-user "$USER" --property=Linger | grep -q 'yes'
```

Comment: Why not use this: "check the existance of /var/lib/systemd/linger"?

Comment: Because it's more subject to changes without notice.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work on systemd 248.3-1ubuntu8.6 on my Ubuntu 21.10 install. `loginctl show-user` doesn't show me any property that has the word "linger" in it.  And `loginctl user-status` shows me the linger status at the top, but does not support `--property=` for filtering. But the `ls` answer works, so looks like that's what I'll have to use.

Comment: @Cliff I had the same issue until I noticed `loginctl show-user` and `loginctl show-user $USER` give completely different outputs. The latter shows `Linger`.

Comment: Notice that the show-user command might fail like "Failed to get user: User ID 1001 is not logged in or lingering" when testing for a different user than the main user logged user (after running `loginctl enable-linger otheruser` then the show-user command no longer fails)