# Stay Logged Into Headless Server

Tags: ssh, systemd, headless

I have a headless Linux server running some services without root access (username `leo`), via `systemd --user`. I ssh into my server (as `leo`), start the services, and then exit. The problem is, systemd sees that the last instance of `leo` has logged out of the system and proceeds to stop all services owned by `leo`.

I've discovered a workaround: running `/usr/bin/ssh -t -N localhost` on the server every time I reboot the system and log in for the first time. A background ssh session keeps me logged in so the services do not disappear after I log out.

This is just that: a workaround. There has to be a proper, better way to do this, but I haven't figured it out. I'd like to do things properly if possible. Is there an officially supported way of staying logged in (via systemd) and if not, is there a more robust solution to this problem? (This will die if I restart sshd, for example.)

Comment: `loginctl enable-linger leo` - see https://serverfault.com/questions/846441/loginctl-enable-linger-disable-linger-but-reading-linger-status